# How to pass parameter when duplicating object in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, controller, clone

How can I provide `.dup` method with custom param so every time it is executed param is always `True` even when object who is being duplicated has this param at false?

Attribute I want to make `true` is called `:original`.

Here is my Modifications_controller `create` action:

```
def create
    @modification = Modification.new(change_params.merge(user: current_user))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @modification.save

        @modification.entity.boxes.each do |b| 
          @modification.boxes << b.dup #here I need to pass custom param
        end

        format.js {}
      else
        format.js {} 
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#dup` doesn't know anything specific about your model logic. If you want to set some attributes to `true`, simply clone the object and then change the values.

```
box = b.dup
box.value = true
@modification.boxes << box
```

You can also consider to extract the feature in a custom method in the model, so that it's easier to write a test for it.

```
def duplicate
  self.dup.tap do |i|
    i.value = true
  end
end

@modification.boxes << b.duplicate
```

Comment: I'm getting this error for your second solution: `undefined method 'duplicate' for #<Box:0x007f3e0c42da50>`

Comment: That's because you didn't define the method.